# Visit method not found in my rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, jruby

**My java web application is running on tomcat at http://localhost:8080/**

Writing my first spec, home_spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'


describe "home" do

    it "should render the home page" do
       visit "/"

       page.should have_content("hello world")
    end

end
```

And running:

```
rspec
```

I get:

```
F

Failures:

  1) home should render the home page
     Failure/Error: visit "/"
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x242870b7>
     # ./spec/home/home_spec.rb:7:in `(root)'

Finished in 0.012 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/home/home_spec.rb:6 # home should render the home page
```

**Shouldn't this work because I have included capybara in the spec_helper?**

How will it know to visit the correct url?  what if my url is localhost:3030 or localhost:8080?

My gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem "activerecord"
gem "rspec"
gem "capybara"
gem "activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter"
```

My spec_helper:

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
```

Answer (score 135):

Regarding to rspec issues (https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/360)

you should put

```
config.include Capybara::DSL
```

in **spec_helper.rb**, inside the config block.

Comment: This fixed it for me in a Rails app 3.2.9. I really wonder what the actual problem is though. I wonder if `--no-test-unit` when you create a rails app affects this some how.

Comment: I think better and recommended solution is rename spec/requests to spec/features

Comment: @Artur79 -- I renamed `spec/integration` (in my case) to `spec/features` and that didn't help. Modifying `spec_helper.rb` per the above answer did, though.

Comment: Now need to be added to `rails_helper.rb`.

Comment: Also add `config.include Capybara::RSpecMatchers`

Answer (score 23):

The default directory that `Capybara::RSpec` now looks at to include the `Capybara::DSL` and `Capybara::RSpecMatchers` is changed from `requests` to `features`.

After I renamed my `requests` directory to `features` I got the matcher and DSL methods available again without having to explicitly include them.

See the following [commit](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/commit/de34c638354c117f20269b4fd129c2657b01ef12)

Comment: also rename the "describe" to "feature"

Comment: Great explanation.Thank you. But instead of changing the directory name, I just followed @egezer's solution. Both works.

Comment: Renaming (moving tests from) spec/requests to spec/features is recommended. See: http://www.andylindeman.com/2012/11/11/rspec-rails-and-capybara-2.0-what-you-need-to-know.html

Comment: The rspec-rails docs have good tips on the default location for each type of test: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails

Comment: Let me add: 
Both `requests` and `features` are allowable directories, but for different purposes. Though renaming your directory *will* work, you may want to ensure the type of spec you are writing is in the proper place. That is, if you want to use `visit` (aka, capybara stuff), then put those specs in a features directory, and leave request-style specs in the `requests` directory.

Answer (score 9):

Also make sure your tests are in the **/spec/features** directory. According to [rspec-rails and capybara 2.0](http://alindeman.github.com/2012/11/11/rspec-rails-and-capybara-2.0-what-you-need-to-know.html), Capybara v2 and higher will not be available by default in RSpec request specs. They suggest to "...move any tests that use capybara from spec/requests to spec/features."

Answer (score 6):

By default the capybara DSL is included automatically if the file is in spec/requests, spec/integration or if the example group has `:type => :request`.

Because your file is in spec/home the capybara helpers aren't being included. You can either conform to one of the patterns above or adding `include Capybara::DSL` should also do the trick (you might also need to replicate some of the `before(:each)` stuff that would be setup.)

Comment: I renamed spec/home/home_spec.rb to spec/requests/home_spec.rb and it didn't change anything.  adding the include I now get: `rack-test requires a rack application, but none was given`

Comment: should I put a folder for support inside the requests folder?  i.e. /spec/requests/support/env.rb ?

Comment: Ah, I'd missed that you weren't testing a rails app. You'd need at the very least to set the capybara driver to selenium, but other than that I'm not sure

Comment: does it automatically load up spec/requests/support/env.rb or I have to do this somehow?   or should I put it in /spec/support/env.rb ??

Answer (score 1):

[First check it out](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/503)

If you are not success,

Add this code your end of the your spec helper actually out of the RSpec.configure block as well

```
module ::RSpec::Core
  class ExampleGroup
    include Capybara::DSL
    include Capybara::RSpecMatchers
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

1) Add to ‘rails_helper’ config:

```
config.include Capybara::DSL
config.include Capybara::RSpecMatchers

And comment out the `require 'spec_helper'` line.
```

2) Add to 'spec_helper':

```
require 'rails_helper'
```