# Ruby on Rails TDD; Error while testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, rspec-rails, railstutorial.org

I am trying to follow TDD on Rails Tutorial which is available online [here](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages?version=3.2#sec%3afirst_tests)

While testing first app, I got an error.

My spec.rb code is this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do
  describe "Home page" do

    it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      page.should have_content('Sample App')
    end
  end
end
```

After running testing I got this error:

```
Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/home'
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `visit' for #    <RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0xa833e5c># ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862967/visit-method-not-found-in-my-rspec

Comment: What is the file's path and name? Is it spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb like in the tutorial? Rspec is quite "magical" about its available and included test helpers and methods based on the name of the file, I have found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `visit` method is not part of RSpec - it's provided by [capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara). Just add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'capybara'
```

Comment: I already have capybara installed but I get the same error? I see capybara 1.1.2 installed in my gemfile list and also "gem list" command results. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @scaryguy Just a shot in the dark - try `include Capybara::DSL` in your `spec_helper.rb` or directly in your spec.

Comment: @Thilo I resolved the issue yesterday, thanks anyway :) At the moment, I'm busy with pulling my hair working on nokogiri...

Comment: @scaryguy how did you resolve this issue? Im curious as i have the same issue. I tried including Capybara::DSL in spec_helper.rb but it warns me not to include capybara in a global space... ?

Comment: I'm sorry @sambehera I really don't remember, it's been a while since I worked on that project.

Comment: thanks for feedback.. i figured out how to bypass the Capybara::DSL part by reading the capybara github readme. TY.

Answer (score 0):

Try add:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'spec_helper'
```

to your spec.rb
and:

```
require 'capybara'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL 
....
```

to spec_helper.rb

and gem 'capybara', '2.2.0' to gemfile