# Ruby on Rails , Rspec Error while testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I am following the tutorial from Michael Hartl . I tried the first test example for testing the app with Rspec and when I execute this command **"bundle exec rspec spec\requests\static_pages_spec.rb"** I get this error.

```
F

Failures:

  1) Home page should have the content 'Sample App'
     Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/home'
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x39e1510 @example=nil>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.001 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:3 # Home page should have the content 'Sample App'
```

**static_pages_spec.rb**

```
describe "Home page" do
  it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do
    visit '/static_pages/home'
    page.should have_content('Sample App')
 end
end
```

**Gemfile.rb**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.10.0'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Comment: @ronalchn Check out the entire error message.

Comment: Please see [visit method not found in my spec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862967/visit-method-not-found-in-my-rspec).

Comment: The problem is not with content of the page . 'visit' is not recognized. @Dave - For visit to work you need the capybara and that's installed . Don't know why this is still happening

Comment: @Dave - Thanks . I read it fully and it says By default the capybara DSL is included automatically if the file is in spec/requests , so since my static_pages_spec.rb is inside spec/requests it should'nt be a problem . Please advice .

Comment: See this discussion: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/360 might be relevant, but depends on what's in spec_helper.rb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `require 'spec_helper'` in your spec source.

Your `spec_helper` should include both `rspec/rails` and `capybara/rails` in it.

You'll want to use `get` instead of `visit` if you want to access the response, however.

Comment: Wow ! Got it working . @Dave : Thanks a lot. Did exactly the above things and it worked . T

Answer (score 1):

If **static_pages_spec.rb** has string `require 'spec_helper'` and you get

> Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/home'

- add to **spec_helper.rb** string `config.include Capybara::DSL`

it helped me