# RubyGems Install Failed Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation

I am trying to install rubygems1.8 in Ubuntu 11.04

I did

```
sudo apt-get install rubygems1.8
```

Then when I do

```
gem install rubygems-update
```

I get

> The program `gem` is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install rubygems1.8
> ```

I tried doing `sudo apt-get install rubygems1.8` again and I get

> rubygems1.8 is already the newest version

As far as I browsed the internet, this method seems to work for everyone. Any idea for troubleshooting?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall : I should accept when the answer solves my problem right ?  Please advice

Comment: You could have marked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255432/ruby-on-rails-rspec-error-while-testing as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/ (which in turn quotes [this](http://news.ycombinator.org/item?id=2039438)):

> Under no circumstance should you install Ruby, Rubygems or any
>   Ruby-related packages from apt-get. This system is out-dated and leads
>   to major headaches. Avoid it for Ruby-related packages.

Comment: @prusswanThanks for the advice . I am trying to set up ruby on rails on apache and following this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RubyOnRails which is well document. Are you saying then these are outdated ?

Comment: @premprakash unless you are dealing with a really old Ubuntu version (<= 9.04) and rails 2.x, I would reckon your hopes are better placed in one of the established and current ruby package managers (rvm, rbenv etc).

Answer (score 1):

If you search any questions here about installing ruby from `apt-get`, they will all the same thing. Use [RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/).