# How to put asserts in Selenium webdriver Ruby script?

Tags: ruby, automation, selenium-webdriver, assertions

I wish to check value on UI with the provided value in script. And on comparing these two, it should display message "test passed" in console.

I have written following code: -

```
browser.find_element(:xpath,"//*[@id="total"]/tbody/tr/td[4]/span").value.should == "$466,634,599.67"
```

But it does not display anything on console. What could be required next?

Thanks!
Abhishek

Comment: Are you using a test framework - example Cucumber, RSpec, etc.? Getting the framework to output to console might be different than a non-framework script.

Comment: @JustinKo I haven't used any test framework. This is my first attempt at automation and I have plain script that requires Selenium Webdriver and commands like above that do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assertions, eg the `.should==`, are typically used within a test framework such as RSpec, MiniTest, Cucumber, etc. These test frameworks are designed to have reporting of the assertion's pass or fail result.

Given that you are not using a test framework, you will need to manually handle the output of results.

The most straightforward way would be to drop the assertion part and use an `if` statement:

```
element_value = browser.find_element(:xpath,"//*[@id="total"]/tbody/tr/td[4]/span").text
if element_value == "$466,634,599.67"
  puts 'Test passed'
else
  puts 'Test failed'
end
```

Note that the `puts` statements are used to output results to the console (unless you have changed the default output location).

Alternatively, if you do want to use the assertion, you could do:

```
element_value = browser.find_element(:xpath,"//*[@id="total"]/tbody/tr/td[4]/span").text
element_value.should == "$466,634,599.67"
puts 'Test passed'
```

In this approach, the assertion will raise an exception if the test fails. The assertion would stop the execution of the code and would therefore not output the 'Test passed' message (as expected). If the test passes, the 'Test passed' message would get outputted.

Comment: I tried using .value but it prints the value nil in stead of actual value.

 browser.find_element(:css,"#total > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4) > span").attribute('value')

 browser.find_element(:css,"#total > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4) > span").value


Neither works!

Comment: You probably want to do `.text` instead of `.value`. There apparently is no `.value` method for spans in Selenium-Webdriver. `attribute('value')` gets the value of the attribute value, which your span element likely does not have.

Answer (score 0):

I use [capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) gem for this purpose. It can check almost all front-end possibilities.
Code should look something like this:

```
describe "User pages" do
  subject { page }
  describe "index" do
    before(:each) do
      sign_in user
      visit users_path
    end
    it { expect(page).to have_selector('li', text: user.name) }
end
```

Comment: I am newbie to automation, do I have to write entire script again in Capybara?

Comment: Add "gem 'capybara'" to Gemfile first and run bundle install. Then follow [this](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-rspec) instruction. And at the end you may be need to add some hack from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862967/visit-method-not-found-in-my-rspec) to get capybara work (last answer works for me). Good luck.

Comment: But would I have to write entire test script again in Capybara or just integrate Capybara and continue further?

Comment: Capybara just adds some methods to your specs. You need to set subject { page }, and visit URL in before block for using it.